# "Der Brief ist erfolgreich an den Empfänger übergeben worden"-why not "übergegeben"

Tags: meaning, passive

Here is a sentence taken from the Linguee dictionary:

> Der Brief ist erfolgreich an den  Empfänger übergeben worden

My question is why is it "übergeben" and not "übergegeben"?

Answer (score 1):

That is because the Partizip II of *übergeben* is ***übergeben***. Without an extra *-ge-*. This is the same as for the other inseparable prefixed verbs — they don't get an extra *-ge-*.

Compare:

- *umfahren, es fährt um, es fuhr um, es hat umgefahren — to run over*
- *umfahren, es umfährt, es umfuhr, es hat umfahren — to run around*

Answer (score -2):

Many prefixed verbs do not use *ge-* to form the participle.

> *gehen*: Er ist gegangen

> *vergehen*: Die Zeit war [schnell] vergangen.

Phrases like that incorporate adverbs like *erfolgreich*. It is quite likely that *ge-* has fossilized in this construction. The etymology of *folgen* is uncertain, possibly compounded with **ga-*: 1. en.wiktionary tentatively suggests a compound of Proto-Germanic **fullaz* (“full”) and **gāną (“to go”). 2. Guus Kroonen (2013) speculates that **gāną* is from **ga-* + a verb represented by Latin *eo*, English *yode*, etc. in a suppletive paradigm. Wiktionary disagrees, however.

The origin of ga-participles is difficult. As far as I know it is ultimately uncertain. Nevertheless, *ge-* < **ga-* is usually compared to Latin *co-, com-, con-* and more to reconstruct Proto-Indo-European **ḱóm-*. Appart from that, the reconstruction of fairly basic verbs like *geben* and *gehen* may be uncertain, although one would think that the etymology, i.e. the real meaning seems reasonably clear.

With this in mind it appears quite possibly to be fossilized from *uber* + *ge(m)* + a be-verb, parallel to Latin *-bam* (active imperfect indicative form of a verb, *amābam* ― I was loving) and similar constructions.

Inasmuch as the rectus *worden* is thus redundant, it is often omitted:

> Der Brief ist übergeben.

As said, this isn't quite clear. That's *why*.

*How?* That would be a different matter. It is possible that too many examples obscure the causes because they are subject to analogy. Therefore I will leave it alone.